# Is it correct to say a state-space model has the Markov property?

Tags: markov-process, control-theory

in control theory, there exists a mathematical model of a control loop, called the state-space model. It allows for the computation of a state vector $x$ at discrete time $k$. For the computation, it requires knowledge of the previous state vector at $k-1$ only.

So, I wonder: Is it correct to say the state-space model has the Markov property? Markov property is also called memoryless property, but it is defined in the context of probability distributions. So I am not sure if my statement is valid.

Comment: Well, you can say almost everything if you properly explain what you mean. :) But if you ask if this is a common saying in the control community, then I would rather say "no". You can speak about Markov jump systems, no problem, but typically we do not say "Markov property" for an arbitrary system.

Comment: thx, Arastas! So you say "Markov property" is not commonly said within this context. Is "memoryless property" used? Or neither? I mean, isn't this one of the crucial properties of a state-space model?

Comment: I can only say that I did not ever see someone using any special term to describe this property.

Answer (score 1):

Markov property is related to the probabilistic model of the state-space equations.
$$ \begin{array}{l}
{{\bf{x}}_k} = {{\bf{f}}_{k - 1}}({{\bf{x}}_{k - 1}},{{\bf{u}}_k}) + {{\bf{v}}_k} \Leftrightarrow p({{\bf{x}}_k}|{{\bf{x}}_{k - 1}},{{\bf{u}}_k})\\
{{\bf{y}}_k} = {{\bf{h}}_k}({{\bf{x}}_k},{{\bf{u}}_k}) + {{\bf{w}}_k} \Leftrightarrow p({{\bf{y}}_k}|{{\bf{x}}_k},{{\bf{u}}_k})
\end{array}$$
where $\bf{v}_k$ , $\bf{w}_k$ are process and measurement noise, respectively.
This state–space representation which incorporate random inputs or noise sources along with random initial conditions, is called Gauss–Markov model.

Under the **first-order Markov** assumption, conditional probability distribution of future states of the process (conditional on both past and present states) depends only upon the present state [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property).

Since any **pth-order Markov** process can be transformed to a first-order process [(1)](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1118210549), [(3)](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=8131728994), then we say that any state-space model has **first-order Markov** property.

Answer (score 0):

A general state space model can be very complicated. [Dynamical systems with hysteresis](https://refubium.fu-berlin.de/bitstream/handle/fub188/7227/Dissertation_Ron.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) will definitely not have the Markov property.

If you can write down your system as

$$x_{k+1} = f(x_k,u_k)$$

then it will have the Markov property because only the current state and the current action/actuation are important for the next state.